# TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)

Tags: python, inheritance, typeerror

I am trying inheritance with Python and got stuck here. Please see what i am missing here. I can only edit the code i have mentioned below, rest is pre defined.

// Below code is Predefined

```
class Person:
def __init__(self, firstName, lastName, idNumber):
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.idNumber = idNumber
def printPerson(self):
    print "Name:", self.lastName + ",", self.firstName
    print "ID:", self.idNumber
```

// I can make changes in below code .

```
class Student(Person):
def __init__(self,firstName,lastName,idNumber,scores):
    super().__init__(firstName,lastName,idNumber)
    self.scores = scores
def calculate(self):
    avg = sum(self.testScores) / len(self.testScores)
    if 90 <= avg <= 100:
        return 'O'
    if 80 <= avg < 90:
        return 'E'
    if 70 <= avg < 80:
        return 'A'
    if 55 <= avg < 70:
        return 'P'
    if 40 <= avg < 55:
        return 'D'
    return 'T'
```

// Below code is predefined

```
line = input().split()
firstName = line[0]
lastName = line[1]
idNum = line[2]
numScores = int(input())
scores = list(map(int, input().split()))
s = Student(firstName, lastName, idNum, scores)
s.printPerson()
print("Grade:", s.calculate())
```

Fixed Typo and Error is as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 35, in <module>
    s = Student(firstName, lastName, idNum, scores)
  File "solution.py", line 11, in __init__
    super().__init__(firstName,lastName,idNumber)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: Sidenote: You can compute `total` with the `sum` function, and save some excess code. Heck, you don't even need `total` except to compute `avg`, so you could simplify to `avg = sum(self.testScores) / len(self.testScores)` and avoid computing `total` separately at all.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger, I am using sum function now.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. `Student._init_` should be called `__init__` to be a constructor.

Comment: I fixed the typo, but the problem still persists with new error - TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Answer (score 0):

The initializer for your subclass must be named *exactly* `__init__` (two leading underscores, two trailing underscores). If it has the wrong number of underscores, or a different name, it's just some weirdly named method, but it's not involved when you do `Student(...)`.

You named your initializer `_init_` (only one leading and trailing underscore), so it's not being used, and it goes straight to the super class's `__init__`, which you passed too many arguments to. Fix the name of `Student`'s initializer, and your problem will go away.

Comment: I fixed the initializer, but problem still persists. This time with -- TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: @Sbk3824: That means you're on Python 2, not Python 3 (in the future, tagging for `python-2.x` vs. `python-3.x` would be helpful here). I'd suggest switching to Python 3 (there is a decent chance you're supposed to be using Python 3, since Python 2 is suboptimal for new programmers), and if that's not possible, you'll need to use explicit calls to the superclass  (your parent is not a new-style class on Python 2 since it doesn't inherit from `object`, and `super` is only for new-style class hierarchies), e.g. `Person.__init__(self, firstName, lastName, idNumber)`.